# how to count 2 table into another one in access 2013?

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 system log table in access 2013, one is loged by email and another one is loged by userid.
log1

> email datetime msg

log2

> userid datetime msg

I want to count how many msg the user send by month and save into a table user_msg_count

> yearmonth userid msg_count

```
SELECT format([log1].datetime,"yyyy/mm") AS yearmonth, log1.email, COUNT(log1.msg) AS msg_count INTO user_msg_count
FROM log1
GROUP BY FORMAT(log1.datetime,"yyyy/mm", log1.email;
```

then I get userid from users table

users

> userid email

```
UPDATE user_msg_count, users SET user_msg_count.userid = users.userid
WHERE user_msg_count.email = users.email;
```

but I dont know how to plus the log2 into the user_msg_count table.

Comment: I don't fully understand. A user has messages in `log2`. A user also has messages in `log1` (via their email). And `user_msg_count` is yet another table? How is that table defined? What is its unique key? Is it one record per user? Why do you even have this table? Why do you want to store a message count redundantly when you can simply count the messages whenever you want?

Comment: Agree with Thorsten, don't see how can justify saving this calculation to a table. If these tables are both for logging emails, why do you even have two tables?  Are the same messages logged in both tables? If you count both tables and add those counts, aren't you double counting? Why isn't UserID saved into Log1?

Comment: the log1 come from website only loged email and log2 come from mobile only loged userid, so I need combine and count how many msgs user send to us.

Answer (score 0):

Is the email the sender (User) email or the receipient?

If User email:

LogUnion query:

```
SELECT Users.UserID, Format([DateSend],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, "L1" AS Source FROM Users INNER JOIN Log1 ON Users.emailAdd = Log1.email
UNION ALL SELECT UserID, Format([DateSend],"yyyymm"), "L2" FROM Log2;
```

TotalCount query:

```
SELECT LogUnion.UserID, LogUnion.YrMo, Count(*) AS CountMsg
FROM LogUnion
GROUP BY LogUnion.UserID, LogUnion.YrMo;
```

Nested all-in-one query:

```
SELECT LogUnion.UserID, LogUnion.YrMo, Count(*) AS CountOfSource
FROM (SELECT Users.UserID, Format([DateSend],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, "L1" AS Source FROM Users INNER JOIN Log1 ON Users.emailAdd = Log1.email
UNION ALL SELECT UserID, Format([DateSend],"yyyymm"), "L2" FROM Log2) AS LogUnion
GROUP BY LogUnion.UserID, LogUnion.YrMo;
```

Comment: thanks, combine msg in one table then count, is it possible to do it in one query? I just want to count msg, it's better not have duplicate msg talbe to reduce table size.

Comment: I don't think table size is an issue. A single table would be preferable to resorting to UNION query. Are there other fields in the tables? See revised answer.

Comment: This must be `UNION ALL`. With `UNION` you remove duplicates, so you only see *whether* a user sent messages, not how many.

Comment: Yes, good point. There could be multiple msg in each table for same user/email for same date. Revised answer.